# Openstack Swift fallocate_reserve option not working

Tags: linux, openstack, swift

I'm using `fallocate_reserve = 5368709120` as an option in account, container and object confs, to make sure 5G reserve space remains on the disks and the the disks does not get filled up.

However, while uploading larger objects, it does not limit or move over to other free disk, but keeps filling same disk after reserve to 100%, even though above reserve option of 5G is used.
Can you help or guide please?